# Is it possible to send commands to an existing xterm process?

Tags: command, pipe, xterm, bus

I have a running xterm and I want to get a program to pipe some commands to it. Is this possible? If yes, how could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not without help.  Someone recently asked a similar question about `screen`.  It turns out that `screen` can accept commands, as discussed in [Run commands in screen after creating one per bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774681/run-commands-in-screen-after-creating-one-per-bash/28776005#28776005).

So, you could run (a named session of) `screen` in an `xterm` and send commands to *that*.